# Debugging A Window System Service in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, service

I get the error "Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger.  A Windows Service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool or the NET START command.

So, is there not a way to run or test the Windows Service without installing it?  Should I build my project in a Console Application, then transfer the code to a Windows Server project after it has been tested?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to add a static Main method to my service class so that it can be invoked as a console application for debugging, but installed and ran as a service as well.

Something similar to the following:

```
    public partial class ControllerService : ServiceBase
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ControllerService service = new ControllerService();

            cmdLine = CommandLineParser.Parse(args);

            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                switch (cmdLine.StartMode)
                {
                    case StartMode.Install:
                        //Service Install Code Here
                        break;
                    case StartMode.Uninstall:
                        //Service Uninstall Code Here
                        break;
                    case StartMode.Console:
                    default:
                        service.OnStart(args);
                        consoleCloseEvent.WaitOne();
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceBase.Run(service);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
             //Do Start Stuff Here
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                consoleCloseEvent.Set();
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: I think I have to try this approach, looks a lot better than the one I'm using

Comment: @gwhitake how would you access service.Onstart its not accessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @ClearLogic - service.OnStart() is accessible because you are calling it from inside the service class.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to keep the code that performs the actual work in a separate assembly, and call that code from the service or a console application for testing.

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches you can use.

1. Create separate windows form application and call that code from the windows form project.
2. in the calling method, please use:

   ```
    #if Debug
    Debugger.Launch()
    #endif
   ```

I hope it helps.